# C++ List Index Query

Tags: c++, list, indexing

For the STL data structure, list, does the index begin at 0 or 1? The online material regarding this is confusing..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesnt have an index. It is implemented as doubly linked list. Only arrays have index. If you need index use vector or deque.  they lack direct access to the elements by their position as there is no random access iterator for list.

Read [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/) for more information on lists.

Comment: i hope its what he means :D maybe he is trying to use index on list.

Comment: I was thinking of the vector and array index, never done lists before... thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: Vector is array implementation and List is Linked list.

Answer (score 0):

`std::list` doesn't really have/use any integer index. When you need to specify a position (or  get a position, such as with a search algorithm) it'll be in terms of an iterator, not an index.